# Fix historical data with mean when data has no change with python dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some historical data that looks like:

```
    d1  d2  d3  d4
p1   1   2   2   4
p2   2   2   2   10
```

I know there is an error when there is not change from one day to another so I want to replace the repeated values with the mean value of the adjacent values and when there is a repeated continuous value more than twice it should be proportional.
So this data should look like this:

```
    d1  d2   d3  d4
p1   1   2   3*   4
p2   2  4*   8*  10
```

Where * means it was "fixed". There is an already existing function for that, or should I iterate manually over the data?

Comment: 8 will be the mean of what adjacent values?

Comment: The 4 and 8 I got them: (2 + 10) / 3
So my first third is 4, second is 8 and third is d4 (10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to `interpolate` where the values have not changed on the same row from one column to the next one. You can replace the repeated data with nan thanks to `mask`, and use `shift` to check where the value is repeated.

```
print (df.mask(df.eq(df.shift(axis=1))).interpolate(axis=1))
     d1        d2        d3    d4
p1  1.0  2.000000  3.000000   4.0
p2  2.0  4.666667  7.333333  10.0
```

but to get the 4 and 8, not sure the rule you could use.

Comment: Ok I think it's even better than my 4 and 8, thanks so much